# How to use a single slicer to manipulate multiple plots in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have multiple tables, all having one common column like:

Table1 => datetime, val1; Table2 => datetime, val2...

I have multiple plots on my page using these tables, and dont want to make changes to my tables
I want to create a single slicer to manipulate all these plots on the page. How do I do this in PowerBI

And also, how to do the same using a common filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the slicer to the page, it will automatically apply to all visuals on that page, IF the slicer has a logical connection to the data.

If you have different fact tables that all have a datetime column with the same name, then you may need to build a calendar table that has all the dates and create relationships between the different fact tables and the calendar table.

You can then use a slicer with the calendar table date field. Since there is a relationship between your fact tables and the calendar table, the slicer on the calendar date will then also filter the visuals that pull data from the fact tables.

If with "common filter" you are referring to a page filter, again, you can use the calendar table date to filter the related data from the fact tables.